# Storing ArrayList object data in mySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, json, object

I am creating a web application that has a User object and each User object has an ArrayList of objects (Food) that need to be stored into a table in a mySQL database. I want to store the entire ArrayList into a single column. Would it be better to store it as a Json? Or should I just create a table for each User that stores the individual items of the ArrayList? The only problem I have is that the data would edited quite frequently.

EDIT: I have tables for both Users and Food. The idea is that Users add from the Foods from the Food table to their ArrayList and then I want to store that ArrayList in something.

```
public class User{
  private int id;
  private String username;
  private List<Food> FoodList = new ArrayList<Food>();
}
```

```
public class Food{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private double protein;
  private int calories;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest creating a table for the items on the list, linked to your user table by a foreign key. And I'd also suggest using JPA to handle that.

Comment: That's a terrible idea. Create a separate table for Food and implement 1-n relation(by adding id of User to food) or n-m relation(using join table) - depends on what you really need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help in order to learn how to ask questions effectively on the site. Questions that verge on opinion can sometimes get closed (even if they seem like valid questions).

Answer (score 0):

1. As @ayrton mentions, creating (at least) two tables is a good idea (one for Users and one for Foods).
2. Definitely don't create a table per User
3. As @NeplatnyUdaj mentioned, a join table (where you map Foods to Users) might be warranted (or it could be overkill, depending on your needs).
4. Given the details you've described, JSON is almost certainly not the best approach (this isn't true in all situations, but if you were in such a situation, I'd probably suggest you consider a different type of database).

(Welcome to SO, btw!)

Comment: I have a table for Users and Food already. If I do a join table where will that information be stored? And multiple Users might have selected the same Food so how can I create a join table around that? (I am fairly new to SQL btw. Sorry for my ignorance)